# How to redefine a const in node REPL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I need to redefine a const in the Node REPL because I want to re-run some functions on my history. I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier '_tareas' has already been declared
```

Is there a way to redefine this constant without having to close the REPL and open it again?

Comment: Put it in a `{ ... }` block scope. As the name suggests, you can't reassign a constant in a particular scope.

Comment: If I put things in `{}` then it does not evaluate line by line showing me the result of each line. But I infer from your answer than there is no way to "un-define" consts. Thank you any ways

Comment: If you want to reassign it then use `let` instead of `const` to begin with...

Comment: I know that... I was testing a code copying and pasting in the REPL console

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8309

Comment: Given that REPL is often used to test experimental half-baked code, seems it ought to be looser about a few things, such as letting anything be redefined.  But a low-effort search turns up nothing to "cheat" around const in this context.